# What is purpose of _p.h files?

Tags: c++, qt, header, header-files, coding-style

In Qt Source files, there are two versions of header files, such as:

```
qxmlstream.h
qxmlstream_p.h
```

Why are there _p.h files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're generally private header files, used so that components of a subsystems know about everything but users don't need to.

In other words, something that multiple C source files in Qt might want to know about would be in the private header files if the users of Qt didn't need to know about them.

One example might be a customised memory allocator for your subsystem. Perhaps you know that every memory allocation you make is 128 bytes then you can provide such an allocator:

```
void * malloc128 (void) { ... }
```

Since this is likely to be of dubious value to users of your subsystem, there's no point publishing it as part of the official API but *every* single one of your own source files needs the prototype so you'd put it in the private header file.

Then your own code uses:

```
#include "mysubsystem_p.h"
```

while users of your API use:

```
#include "mysubsystem.h"
```

Answer (score 3):

Qt need to maintain stable external link-level interface. To solve that they use next approach:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  size_t compatSize();
private:
  MyClassPrivate *data;
};


// implementation
struct MyClassPrivate {
  int someFieldThatCanChange;
};
size_t compatSize() { return (size_t)(data->someFieldThatCanChange); }
```

By doing that change of implementation doesn't affect size and structure of `MyClass`. And you still able to add new fields or remove old one.
Other approach is to use "interfaces" (abstract classes), factories and virtual functions for every method - which will result in a slower code, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

This can be called a design pattern used to increase the readability of the header files from a given class by hiding everything the user of the class does not need to know about.

So, instead of defining a header file from a given class header that is composed by public and private datas, Qt often chooses to place the private data from a class into a separate class. This separate class is then used as a private member from the original class.

For example instead of having:

```
class MyClass
{

public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    QVariant getValue1();
    QVariant getValue2();
    QVariant getValue3();

private:
    QVariant m_Value1;
    QVariant m_Value2;
    QVariant m_Value3;
};
```

We could have the folowing

```
class MyClass
{

public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    QVariant getValue1();
    QVariant getValue2();
    QVariant getValue3();

private:
    friend class MyClassPrivate;
};
```

where MyClassPrivate is defined like this

```
class MyClassPrivate 
{

public:
    MyClassPrivate ();
    ~MyClassPrivate ();

    QVariant m_Value1;     
    QVariant m_Value2;
    QVariant m_Value3;
};
```

In other words, all private class member are therefore "exported" into the public definition of a privately used class.

For me this is a way to make the header file of the class, the User will deal with, more readable. This is especially true when it comes to classes needing lots of private members.